# Error Query Firestore

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

My query worked fine, until I added: "WhereEqualTo". When I add this, the task never ends.

```
CollectionReference collectionReference = db.collection("eventos");

collectionReference.whereEqualTo("usuario", true).limit(15).orderBy("hora", 
Query.Direction.DESCENDING).get().addOnSuccessListener(new 
OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
```

Comment: First thing to do is [adding an `OnFailureListener`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Task.html#addOnFailureListener(com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener)) to see what error is reported if/when the task fails.

Comment: What is the error that is reported?

Comment: Also check if "usuario" field set to true in your records.

Comment: Error: FAILED_PRECONDITION: The query requires an index. You can create it here: https://console.firebase.google.com/project/duevent33/database/firestore/indexes?create_index=EgdldmVudG9zGgsKB3VzdW.........